# Reorder a string to a string with no consecutive identical characters

Tags: c++, string

The title is pretty self-explanatory, but here's a few examples:

- aabbcc -> abcabc
- abcabc -> cbabac
- cbacbaca -> bcacacba

I figured `std::random_shuffle(myString.begin(), myString.end())` would be interesting since it would never do the same reordering through different calls, but it would need to be looped while the resulting string hasn't similar characters in consecutive positions. Is there a more logical way to do that reordering, or any other function doing something similar?

NOTE: The reordering doesn't need to be done randomly. A sorting function could be used, as long as identical characters are not in consecutive positions.

**UPDATE:** As stated in the comments...yes random_shuffle *could* return the same string order several times in a row. `next_permutation` would be more appropriate assuming the preceding approach.

Comment: The beginnings of a naive solution might build a map of characters to frequency, then simply spit out a new string that repeats those characters in turn with the required frequency. The problem with this is that if one character appears at least two times more than the other characters, you're going to have unavoidable duplicates and then you need to find somewhere to slot them in. This is a _big_ algorithmic problem and probably not something that's specific enough for a Stack Overflow Q&A.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Actually, this was an interview question I was asked and as an answer I came up with something similar with your naive solution and thought it was really too heavy for the task, so I was wondering how others would approach the problem. Thanks for your opinion on the subject and confirming it requires more than 2 minutes of thinking to come up with a solution. Also sorry if I posted it in the wrong Q&A section, I'll gladly change that if the community feels the need to.

Comment: Provided your string has simple properties like the examples you gave, `std::next_permutation` should work ([example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3fdcc0d85b75f4a2)) However, as @LightnessRacesinOrbit mentions, to do this in full generality is non-trivial.

Comment: I must say that statement _"it would never do the same reordering through different calls"_ is false. It is random. It can output same permutation several times in a row. Naive approach would be using `next_permutation` until you find one which suits you

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot yes...It can output the same permutation several times in a row, but I would consider the odds of that happening small, even though it is possible. But I didn't know next_permutation existed which would much more appropriate in this case... thanks for the hint

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for letting me know next_permutation existed. Much appreciated!

Comment: @much_a_chos amount of permutations of 9-character string might be higher than amount of unique sequences RNG commongly used in random_shuffle can provide. So I would not rely on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all note that the solution does not always exist. It exists if and only if the element with most occurrences is present no more than `(n+1)/2`.

So it is easy to check whether solution exists. If it exists then the following code will find it

```
bool cmpBySecond(const std::pair<char, int>& a, const std::pair<char, int>& b) {
    if (a.second == b.second) return a.first < b.first;
    return a.second < b.second;
}

std::string reorder(const std::string& input) {
    std::map<char, int> cnt;
    for (auto& c: input) cnt[c]++;
    auto items = std::vector<std::pair<char, int>>(cnt.begin(), cnt.end());
    std::sort(items.begin(), items.end(), cmpBySecond);
    std::reverse(items.begin(), items.end());
    // now we have chars with occurencies counts in descending order
    std::string result(input);
    int pos = 0;
    for (auto& it: items) {
        char c = it.first;
        int times = it.second;
        for (int i = 0; i < times; ++i) {
            result[pos] = c;
            pos += 2;
            if (pos >= result.size()) pos = 1;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The idea beyond it is to distribute the most frequent element, and then to fill gaps with the rest elements.

Also the same code with some tests [here](https://ideone.com/KnQLIu).

Comment: +1 for the highlight on (n+1)/2 and I believe this kind of approach is the best one with all solutions considered.